# The structure of countable ordinals

Tags: set-theory, arithmetic, ordinals

Consider the recursively defined [hyperoperation sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_operator) $\circ_i$

$$\begin{array}{rcrclclcl}
x& \small{+}&(y\ {\small+}1)&:=&x& &&{\small+}&1\\
x& \boldsymbol{+}&(y\ {\small+}1)&:=&(x& \boldsymbol{+} &y)&{\small+}&x\\
x& \cdot &(y\ {\small+}1)&:=&(x& \cdot& y)&\boldsymbol{+}&x\\
x&\uparrow &(y\ {\small+}1)&:=&(x&\uparrow& y)&\cdot&x\\
x& \uparrow\uparrow &(y\ {\small+}1)&:=&(x&\uparrow\uparrow& y)&\uparrow&x\\
&&&\vdots\\
x& \uparrow^{n+1} &(y\ {\small+}1)&:=&(x&\uparrow^{n+1}& y)&\uparrow^{n}&x\\
&&&\vdots\\
\end{array}$$

with $x \circ_0 y = x {\small+} 1$ (the successor function), $x \circ_1 y = x + y$, $x \circ_2 y = x \cdot y$, $x \circ_3 y = x \uparrow  y = x^y$, and so on. This sequence can be used to define a sequence of successor functions for ordinals:

$$\begin{array}{rcrclclcl}
\mathsf{S}_0(x) &:=& x \circ_0 \omega&=&x&\small{+}& \omega& = &x& \small{+}& 1\\
\mathsf{S}_1(x) &:=& x \circ_1 \omega&=&x&\boldsymbol{+}& \omega\\
\mathsf{S}_2(x) &:=& x \circ_2 \omega&=&x&\cdot& \omega\\
\mathsf{S}_3(x) &:=& x \circ_3 \omega&=&x&\uparrow& \omega\\
&\vdots\\
\end{array}$$

With these successor functions and their respective limits one gets the following picture of the countable ordinals (at least the smaller ones):

[image]

Note that the small dots on every level correspond to the big dots on the level before.

> Is this picture essentially correct and maybe helpful?

---

> Can the limit ordinal labelled ?? (which seems to be countable) be characterized rigorously (not just by dots) and does it have a name or notation, eventually?

---

[**Added**] Thanks to [Miha's suggestion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_sequence_%28ordinals%29#Fundamental_sequences_for_the_Veblen_hierarchy) I learned a little bit about [fundamental sequences](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tf/fundamentalsequence.pdf). So the question is about the limit of the fundamental sequence $\lbrace \omega \uparrow^n \omega\rbrace_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Maybe it's enough to characterize this ordinal just like this. But it would be interesting how it could be characterized otherwise.

[**Added**] Maybe it's trivial, but I had to learn (from [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal)) that the limit ordinal under consideration must be a countable ordinal, because the first uncountable ordinal does'nt have a countable fundamental sequence.

Comment: The limit, it seems to me (off the bat), is not larger than $\omega_1^{CK}$ the least ordinal which cannot be encoded as a recursive relation on the natural numbers. This ordinal is very much countable.

Comment: To see that it is countable (assuming the natural formalization of your picture) notice that it is the limit of the $\omega$-sequence of countable ordinals appearing directly above it in the picture: $0,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots$.

Comment: How are these (limit) ordinals characterized formally: $0, \omega, \omega^2, \omega^\omega$ (to be able to build a formal limit)?

Comment: .. and does this limit have a name or a notation?

Comment: As you said, one can define the sequence of "up-arrow" functions by recursion.  Then one can consider the sequence $(\omega \uparrow^n 1: n < \omega)$.  I'm not sure whether "$1$" is the right thing to put on the right hand side in order to get the sequence $(0,\omega,\omega^2,\omega^\omega,\ldots)$ because I'm not sure what the base case is in the recursive definition for each individual operator.  I don't know of any name for the limit of this $\omega$-sequence.

Comment: I don't know whether your ordinal has a special name, but I would suggest you look at [Veblen functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function) and the [Feferman-Schütte ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feferman%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtte_ordinal).

Comment: Related: [Better bounds on my ordinal hyperoperators](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2558084)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit is $φ_ω(0)$, where φ is the [Veblen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function).

To formally define hyperoperations, you need to define the case $y=0$, and also (for infinite ordinals) the behavior at limit ordinals.  I assume reasonable values at $y=0$, and continuous (or otherwise reasonable) behavior at limit $y$.

Your nesting of parentheses is different from the standard treatment of hyperoperations, which is relevant given non-associativity of exponentiation and higher hyperoperations. For example, in your definition, $x↑↑y = x^{x^y}$ (since $(x^x)^x = x^{x^2}$ and so on).

However, $x ↑^{n+1} (y+1) = (x ↑^{n+1} y) ↑^n x = ((x ↑^{n+1} y) ↑^n (x-1)) ↑^{n-1} (x ↑^{n+1} y)$, so while (for finite arguments) your $↑^n$ is slower (for $n>1$) than the standard $↑^n$, your $↑^{2n}$ is still faster than the standard $↑^n$, and your $↑^n$ has the benefit of working well unmodified for infinite arguments.

$x↑↑↑y$ essentially iterates exponentiation, and if $ω≤x<ε_0$, $x↑↑↑(ω+ωy) = ε_y$.
$(ω+x) ↑^{2n+1} (ω+x)$ is probably between $φ_n(x)$ and $φ_{n+1}(x)$.

However, we do not need precise bounds to get the limit point, which is $φ_ω(0)$.  If we start with 0 and iterate $φ_n$ $ωα$-times, adding 1 at limits to escape the fix-points, the result will be $φ_{n+1}(α)+1$.  The hyperoperations sequence grows at a similar general rate/recurrence, with finite increments of $n$ corresponding to finite increases of $n$ in $φ_n$, so the limit is $φ_ω(0)$.

To go further, you can continue hyperoperations transfinitely (with continuous or otherwise reasonable values at limit $n$).  $↑^{2α}$ (with your nesting of parentheses) will roughly correspond to $φ_α$, and the supremum of ordinals expressible this way (allowing hyperoperations inside $α$) is $Γ_0$.

You can also approach $φ_ω(0)$ with appropriately defined one variable functions/hyperoperations.  For example, set $f_0(x)=x$, $f_n(0)=1$ ($n>0$), and $f_{n+1}(x+1) = f_n(f_{n+1}(x)⋅2)$ with $f_n(x)$ continuous in both $n$ and $x$.  We have $f_ω(x) = φ_ω(0)$ if $ω<x≤φ_ω(0)$; and $Γ_0$ is the least ordinal $α$ such that $f_α(ω+1)=α$.

Comment: Additionally, $\varphi(\omega,0)$ is the least ordinal closed under the primitive recursive ordinal functions (from http://www.madore.org/~david/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf), a nice analog of how each of the original $\uparrow^n$-operators for naturals is primitive recursive.